# Angular Http Post sending nothing

Tags: php, angular

I have a simple code that my PHP will look for any item that has the names "prod_name and prod_desc" and print them.
This is the code:

```php
    echo ($_POST['prod_name']);
    echo ($_POST['prod_desc']);

    exit;
```

```js
makeRequest() {
    let data = {
      'prod_name': 'Celphone',
      'prod_desc': 'A Big Ass Celphone'
    }

     let httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }),
       responseType: 'text' as 'json'
     }


    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/vysor_vendas_online/rest/post.php', data, httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          retry(3),
          tap(console.log),
          catchError(this.errorHandl)
        )
        .subscribe(
          response => console.log(response),
          error => console.error(error)
        )
    }
```

But the response always is:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: prod_name in <b>C:\Fitgroup\ws_fg\www\vysor_vendas_online\rest\post.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: prod_desc in <b>C:\Fitgroup\ws_fg\www\vysor_vendas_online\rest\post.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

But in the Postman app, the request goes just fine. Look:
[Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvznh.png)

What is the problem??

Comment: I'm not sure about your php code, but your sending json data in your code, and postman is sending form data, which is two different payloads.

Answer (score 1):

Your Angular code is using the following HTTP Header :

```
'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
```

to describe your payload type to the back-end server, 
while postman is using a completely different payload type (Form Data),
Either change php code to accept raw JSON, or use this npm package to transfer tour object to form data, [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata)

Comment: In addition to this, you can make sure your code doesn't run and error out when the page is scraped, or any other such page load by first checking if the variable is set: `if (isset($_POST['prod_name']))`

Comment: In my original code i'm sending all the form values , if i'm not wrong, the form values is an object, what is the Content-type that i should use for objects?